# Testing a simple class in models.py django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am trying to test the `PurposeOfVisit` class here and when I create the objects save it and try to retrieve it, in terminal it works just fine but in my test class it shows an error. Can someone please help me as to why I might be getting the error.

```
class PurposeOfVisit(CommonInfo):
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.purpose

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Purpose of Visit"
        verbose_name_plural = "Purposes of Visit"

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
        create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_creator')
        updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_modifier')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This is my tests.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from irms.models import CommonInfo
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpRequest
from irms.models import *
from django.utils import unittest
from irms.models import Customer
from irms.models import Email
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError
from irms.models import PurposeOfVisit

class PersonTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_PurposeOfVisit(self):
        u= User.objects.get(id=1)
        obj= PurposeOfVisit.objects.create(purpose='Badge',
        is_visible=False, created_by=u,updated_by=u)
        obj.save()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(obj,PurposeOfVisit))
```

Comment: What's the error? Just looking at it, it seems like you're trying to get a User without having creating one first for the test case. I'm guessing `DoesNotExist`?

Comment: thanks yes i figured it out i was getting before creating.